# Wicket wrap img element in a link

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have wicket code that shows an image:

```
<div class="someclass">
   <img wicket:id="some-image"/>
</div>
```

This works great.

I have a requirement that sais, that this image MIGHT be wrapped in a link and that link also needs to be generated from the wicket side.

So I would like to implement this the nicest way possible WITHOUT having to add BOTH sections like this:

```
<a wicket:id="link-for-image">
   <div class="someclass">
      <img wicket:id="some-image-with-link"/>
   </div>
</a>

<div class="someclass">
   <img wicket:id="some-image"/>
</div>
```

and hiding one or the other.

What is the standard way of implementing this nicely?

Is there a way to define some kind of generic type for "link-for-image" so I can maybe create it as a web markup container instead of a link?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Also, consider setting the image as background for the link (skipping the need of an IMG tag) and use CSS `display:inline-block` and `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use either `Border`
2. Use fragments
3. Output `<a>` always, but hide `href` attribute.

PS: `<div>` is not allowed inside `<a>` due to HTML standard.

Comment: I would try avoid  using option 3 is possible. I have considered fragment but that seemed to be something else. I'll look into borders as I haven't heard of that yet. Thanks!

Comment: I've ended up using a Border. Works nicely enough. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

If Ajax is an option you can add an onclick behaviour:

```
Image img = new Image("id", yourResource);
img.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // Your click magic
    }
});
add(img);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not actually consider using ajax I didn't think adding ajax behaviour would be so easy. Anyway I'm afraid using ajax is not an option right now, but I appretiate your answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

First, the "disabled link" functionality of AbstractLink might be sufficient for you. Link, BookmarkablePageLink etc. extend AbstractLink.

If not, you can use a subclass of Link (or BookmarkablePageLink, or whatever). Then override onComponentTagBody(), and if the "link" should not be a link, don't add a href and turn the  into a  or . This solution assumes that such a "wrapper" element won't screw up your CSS or scripts. You might be able to turn it into a wicket:container and have that stripped away, if your markup settings are set to strip such tags.